# Show that if $\lambda$ is a Real eigenvalue of U then $|\lambda| = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

**Problem**

Show that if $\lambda \in R$ and $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue of an orthogonal matrix U , then $| \lambda | = 1 \\$

Was given the hint

> *use $U\cdot \hat{x} \ U\cdot \hat{x}$ and $|| \lambda \ \hat{x}|| = |\lambda| \ ||\hat{x}|| \\$*

so I tried this

$U\cdot \hat{x} \ U\cdot \hat{x} =  \lambda \ \hat{x} \ \lambda \ \hat{x}
\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   = {{\lambda}}^2 \ \hat{x} \ \hat{x}
\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   = {{\lambda}}^2 {||\hat{x}||}^2$

I understand that we are using eigen value property   $A\hat{x} = \lambda \hat{x}$

but I'm not sure how to solve the rest

 I was told to use $ {||\hat{x}||}^2 \neq 0$ but I'm not sure why

Comment: What is the definition of an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: vectors are non zero and linear independent, the transpose of the matrix multiplied by itself is the identity... not sure how it corresponds to an Eigen value being 1 , I know that the Eigen value is value by corresponds to matrix transformation on a vector by which a vector is scaled by a value.

Comment: Using $U^TU=I$, try to simplify $\langle Ux,Ux\rangle$.

Comment: okay , UxUx = x $\cdot$ x , therefore lambda has to = 1

Comment: Then $\lambda^2=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Our OP localplutonium was very close; indeed, right on top of a complete solution.

$U$ is orthogonal if and only if $U^TU = UU^T = I$, by definiton.

If $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ is an eigenvalue of $U$, then there is some vector $\vec x \ne 0$ with

$U\vec x = \lambda \vec x; \tag 1$

since $U$ is orthogonal we have

$\langle U\vec x, U \vec x \rangle = \langle \vec x, U^TU \vec x \rangle = \langle \vec x, I \vec x \rangle = \langle \vec x, \vec x \rangle; \tag 2$

using (1) in (2) we thus find

$\langle \lambda \vec x, \lambda \vec x \rangle = \langle U \vec x, U \vec x \rangle = \langle \vec x, \vec x \rangle; \tag 3$

but

$\langle \lambda \vec x, \lambda \vec x \rangle = \lambda^2 \langle \vec x, \vec x \rangle = \vert \lambda \vert^2 \langle \vec x, \vec x \rangle; \tag 4$

combining (3) and (4),

$\vert \lambda \vert^2 \langle \vec x, \vec x \rangle = \langle\vec x, \vec x \rangle, \tag 5$

whence, since $\vec x \ne 0$, so that $\langle \vec x, \vec x \rangle \ne 0$ (and this is where we use $\Vert \vec x \Vert^2 \ne 0$, so we can cancel out $\langle \vec x,  \vec x \rangle = \Vert \vec x \Vert^2$)

$\vert \lambda \vert^2 = 1, \tag 6$

and so

$\vert \lambda \vert = 1 \tag 7$

as well.

Comment: okay thats what I thought, I just didn't think you could divide both sides by x*x

Comment: @localplutonium:  well, as long as $\Vert \vec x \Vert \ne 0$ it's OK!